# Update application placement / Reset origin on Hololens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

**Update**:

```
void Awake() {
    if(UnityEngine.VR.VRSettings.loadedDeviceName.Equals("HoloLens"))
        UnityEngine.VR.InputTracking.Recenter();
}
```

Doesn't appear to do anything. Found [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/reset-hololens-origin.469162/) related post titled, "Reset Hololens Origin" inquiring about a similar behavior. Two individuals affiliated with Unity in someway (both bare the 'Unity technologies' profile tag) brought up InputTracking.Recenter(). One adds, "*[S]ome changes landed recently, and part of those changes were hooking up InputTracking.Recenter properly on WindowsMR.*"

The snippet of code I include above is an attempt to implement this behavior. I most definitely could be trying to call this code in an improper/incorrect location but, as it is now, I do not see it working.

**end update**

When a user opens a Unity Hololens application they are given control over where the application starts by giving them a generic white box to denote the application and allowed to place it any where via the air tap gesture.

Problem:
If a user blooms out of the application but does not close this white box, the application is left in a suspended or 'tombstoned' state. When the application is opened again, the Hololens remembers the old white box placement and reloads the application their.

This isn't desired behavior as with multiple users and or a variety of locations, the application appears to not be loading to the user when the Hololens is bringing the suspended application back into the running state but not updating its position to current user gaze.

Question:
Can one detect, in awake, where the user is looking and move the application manually?

UnityEngine.WSA.Application.windowActivated : Fired when application window is activated.
Somewhere like this?

Any google searches on this question or variations in wording turn up nothing. Unsure of the possibility of moving the app itself.

If this isn't possible would the next alternative be to force the app to close when I want, say for example, in the suspended state? In an attempt to prevent this type of multiple apps open situation.

Comment: Rather than recentering the hololens device, it sounds like you want to restart (from zero) the *application.*

Comment: @Draco18s Correct. To ensure an optimal user experience, the app should always open and display directly in front of their gaze. This happens on initial open (if no previous instance of the app is was created and left opened [in the suspended / 'tombstone' state]), where as if an instance is open, when the user goes to open the app, it will re-open at the suspended location. This should not happen. The app itself needs to be moved back into the users gaze.

Comment: That makes sense, glad I understood. I don't have any suggestions though, I only had 4 months of exposure with the device and that particular use-case was not important for us so I never looked into it.

Comment: @Draco18s Understood, though I will say surprised no one on your team encountered this issue in four months of usage. Perhaps reloading the scene might do the trick but I doubt it

Comment: You mean the team of "me and a guy in india?" And no, it didn't come up, because we were recompiling the application 12 times a day: every time you do that, the application is terminated and restarted fresh.

Comment: @Draco18s Apologies if I offended, wasn't sure how else to term your usage of us in "...not important for **us**". Recompiling the Unity app multiple times a day is a hassle. Rebuild Unity app, refresh App solution in VS (or in whichever IDE one is using), rebuild App for Remote/Local Machine, et cetera et cetera. I sympathize. Perhaps, "I am surprised you yourself and those whom you worked with..." was more appropriate.

Comment: I was teasing with that part of my comment. :) I'm sure it came up when the app was being demo'd to management/clients, but as I was never privy to those meetings (and little feedback was provided) it hadn't been anything I looked into. I suspect the concern lay mostly on developing features ("Can we make it do X?") over things like this.